# List all the actionable elements in a web page

Tags: java, selenium, html-parsing

I'm trying to write a java method that will be able to return the number of objects that are clickable and trigger an action (preferably excluding hyperlinks) in a web page. Examples of actionable objects are buttons, image buttons, etc.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Well every pixel on a page is clickable. Whether it triggers an action is a different story.

Comment: Right! I'm modifying the question accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no universal solution for this problem.

In particular case, you'll need to inject javascript code from webdriver, which will query the specific javascript framework (jQuery, YUI, Prototype) for list of defined event handlers.

In the following thread:

[How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node), a great tool,

**[Visual Events](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event)** and **[Visual Events 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2)** had been mentioned. This tools shows event bindings from multiple frameworks and it is opensource.